# If text input from html is being used in javascript as chart js background color is it vunerable to xss?

Tags: javascript, xss

I have been trying to understand xss. I have some code that looks like this...
HTML
`<input type="text" name="" id="colourChoice1" value=""></input>`

JAVASCRIPT

```
 function colourChoice1Javascript(){
       colourChoice1 = document.getElementById('colourChoice1').value;
      console.log(colourChoice1);
    }
```

colourChoice1 is then used in chartjs code to set the backgroundcolour (as below)

```
const data = {


          labels: xValues,

          datasets: [{
            label: userCommonBatsDataName,
            backgroundColor: colourChoice1,
            borderColor: 'black',
            data: y2Values
          }
```

I am new to javascript and would like to know if this is vulnerable to xss or anything else. I have read around for a while now and can not seem to find the answer. Do I need to create a new variable after colour1 that has the tags stripped so that when it is added to the chartjs code it is encoded?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Yes, it (as well as all inline styling) is dangerous.

Comment: You can virtually eliminate script injection using a content-security-policy